# Hadoop: ClassNotFoundException $Reduce

Tags: java, hadoop

I've got a *word count* example class called by a Jetty server's handle method. The job is submitted with:

`JobClient.runJob(conf);`

Sadly, the JobTracker sees nothing, the job does not get submitted, but it finishes and creates output. I've found out, that I have to inject my configurations with:

`conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml"));`

After adding this line, the JobTracker gets the job, but it fails with the following exception:

```
INFO: Task Id : attempt_201312071601_0005_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WC2$Reduce
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getCombinerClass(JobConf.java:1049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$CombinerRunner.create(Task.java:1385)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.<init>(MapTask.java:986)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WC2$Reduce
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:857)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:881)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WC2$Reduce
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:810)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:855)
    ... 11 more
```

My combiner class is the same as the reducer class. I've downloaded the Hadoop WordCount example without modifications. Only the mentioned `addResource`.

Comment: have you added hadoop jar while running the program?

Comment: How to you mean "added"?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326459/hadoop-classnotfoundexception?rq=1

Comment: Doesn't seem related.

Comment: Make sure the nested reduce class is public (and probably static) so that the Hadoop system can instiate it.

Comment: It is public (also static).